# Hot to navigate to home fragment from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am new to Android programming though I am coding in another languages. I am not able to navigate to home fragment in a particular scenario.

I have three fragments among few more viz., Settings, Capacity and About. All these can be reached via Overflow Toolbar menu items. Settings can be reached thru another button on home fragment.

Use case 1: Click Settings button on home fragment. Settings open. In Settings use either Up/Home or Back Button. On clicking any one of them, home fragment is reached.

Use case 2: Click Toolbar overflow menu(three dots). Three menu item appears. Select Settings menu item. Settings Open. In Settings, use either Up/Home or Back Button. On clicking any one of them, home fragment is reached.

Use Case 1 is working fine. I think nav_graph defined is used here where navigation between fragments is defined.

Use Case 2 fails. Upon pressing Up/Home button or Back button, I get white screen rather landing on home fragment.

I studied code in several websites including SO and official Android site. But could not make out what kind of code to be used when navigating back to home fragment from another fragment(which was particularly reached via Toolbar menu and outside of nav_graph).

I studied methods in stack in debug window. But did not help me either.

Please enlighten me the approach to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued searching for solution to my problem. I came across a solution in `https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/learn-android-navigation-component-through-coding-79dc47b240b3`  It worked perfectly well and solved white screen issue and also not using explicit method using fragment manager for traversing to another fragment. It was about linking menu items to navigation graph.

Answer (score 0):

First set Home Fragment in content view(frame view).
on top you can your next fragment kinda stack of fragments 1 above another.
create method in activity this method will popout all fragments except Home Fragment.

Add Fragment use below code

```
    Fragment fragment = new FragmentHome();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment).addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();
```

To go Home clearing all

```
    public void goToHome()
{
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    for(int i = 0; i < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()-1; ++i)
    {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Comment: They said they are using the [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/), which means you should not ever be using `FragmentManager` directly at all.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, in that case how do I integrate Navigation Component with Toolbar menu items for Use Case 2.  In the present code, I am traversing to Settings Fragment thru fragment manager when the user opts to select Settings from Toolbar menu.

Comment: @Nilesh, which method in activity will invoke goToHome?

Comment: yes call  goToHome method from anywhere activity or fragment itself

Comment: @Nilesh, It did not work. The sequence is Home Fragment > Settings (via toolbar item selection) > Up/Home Button click in Settings > Blank screen.  The `fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()` was 0 before toolbar item selection and 1 after toolbar item selection. So, loop in goToHome was exiting without popping out any fragments. I inspected the fragmentManager and there was only one entry of SettingsFragment. So there is no entry for HomeFragment in the backstack.

Comment: @ Nilesh,  If this is the correct behavior, goToHome will not work. If this is not the correct behavior how do I add home fragment to backstack? Or am I in a wrong route to solve the problem? Reason for thinking that I may be in wrong route is that Android developers use toolbar menu to go to other fragments and hence there should be robust methods in Android classes to handle coming back by clicking UP/Home button in tool bar. Should I post the code(let me know what all files required). Thanks for your time and patience.